# How to attach input field value to parameters?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, parameters

How to add to parameters value of input field filled by jquery? When I type content by hand then everything works fine. For some reason dynamically added value is ignored. I'm working with Backbone and Rails.

Hamlc template:

```
.modal-content
  %form.form-signup{name: "session"}
    .modal-header
    .modal-body
      .form-group
        %input.form-control.first{name: "email", :placeholder => "#{I18n.t('email')}", type: "text", :autofocus => "", value: "test@test.com"}
    .modal-footer
      %input#new{type: "submit"}
```

Sample piece of Backbone view:

```
render: ->
  $(@el).find('input[name=email]').val('test@test.com')
```

Received empty parameters:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>""}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can simply pass the params over to the value

```
= text_field_tag 'email', params[:user][:email] || 'test@test.com', class: 'form-control first', placeholder: I18n.t('email')
```

I'm using the rails helper for generating the field instead of just haml, which is generally advised :)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in *.hamlc template. I'll add dynamically value by jquery and then send it but for some reason this value is ignored.